# Android: Custom dialog take too much time to open

Tags: android, list, android-studio, show, customdialog

I have custom dialog which shows listing, it's working but it's take too much time to open, I also tried to solve it using DialogFragment but it's shows as it is, so how can i solve it? please guys help to solve this problem!

MyDialog.java

```
    try {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.ll_weight:
                        mDialogFor = 1;
                        if (mArrWeightList != null && mArrWeightList.size() > 0) {
                            Log.print("mIsDialogueClick:::mArrWeightList::: " + mIsDialogueClick);
                            if (!mIsDialogueClick) {
                                mIsDialogueClick = true;
                                showDialogBox(mDialogFor, txtWeight, getString(R.string.alert_select_weight));                          
                            }
                        }
                        break;
    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.debug(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
                Log.error(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
            }

if (WebInterface.isOnline(mActivity)) {
            new ApiProductDetail(mActivity, handlerProductDetail, mProductId).execute();
        } else {
            Utils.showAlert(mActivity, getString(R.string.title_internet), getString(R.string.Check_Internet_connection), getString(R.string.ok));
        }
    private void showDialogBox(final int mDialogFor, final TextView text, String mHeaderText) {
            TextView txtHeader;
            mDialog = new Dialog(mActivity);
            mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_list);
            //mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            listItem = (ListView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.listFilter);
            txtHeader = (TextView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
            txtHeader.setText(mHeaderText);
            listItem.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

            mDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    mIsDialogueClick = false;
                }
            });

            mDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    mIsDialogueClick = false;
                }
            });

            if (mDialogFor == 1) {
                mProductDetailDialogAdapter = new ProductDetailDialogAdapter(mActivity, mArrWeightList);
                listItem.setAdapter(mProductDetailDialogAdapter);
            } else if (mDialogFor == 2) {
                mTimeListAdapter = new TimeListAdapter(mActivity, mArrTimeList);
                listItem.setAdapter(mTimeListAdapter);
            } else if (mDialogFor == 3) {
                mOccasionListAdapter = new OccasionListAdapter(mActivity, mArrOccasionList);
                listItem.setAdapter(mOccasionListAdapter);
            }

            listItem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    mIsDialogueClick = false;
                    switch (mDialogFor) {
                        case 1:
                            text.setText(mArrWeightList.get(position).weight);
                            mWeightPrice = Double.parseDouble(mArrWeightList.get(position).product_price + "");
                            mWeightId = mArrWeightList.get(position).weight_id;
                            break;
     }
                    calculatePrice();
                }
            });
            mDialog.show();
        }
private Handler handlerProductDetail = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            try {
                if (msg.what == 0) {
                    // ApiDashboard
                    if (msg.arg1 == 1) {
                        productListArrayList = (ArrayList<ProductListBean>) msg.obj;

                        if (productListArrayList != null && productListArrayList.size() > 0) {
mArrWeightList = productListArrayList.get(0).mArrWeightList;
if (mArrWeightList == null) {
                                ll_weight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            } else {
                                for (int i = 0; i < mArrWeightList.size(); i++) {
                                    if (mWeightId.equals(mArrWeightList.get(i).weight_id)) {
                                        mWeightPrice = mArrWeightList.get(i).product_price;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
 }
                    } else if (msg.arg1 == 2) {
                        showSnackbar(mViewPager, getString(R.string.no_data_found));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.error(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
                Log.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e + "");
            }
        }
    };
```